# Function with inputs moved from each other for a distance less than $a$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $a>0$ and $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with a property $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R;$ such that $0\;<\;y\;-\;x\;<\;a$ $$f(x)\;<f(y).$$
Prove if the statements are true or false:

$1)$ $f$ must be injective.

$2)$ $f$ must be surjective.

I tried to use a quarter of a circle with radius $r=a$ or a right-angled triangle and translate it. When I moved it, I saw new values of $f$. I concluded the maximum value in the previous interval can't appear again in another interval when the distance between one point in the first interval and one point in the second is less than $a$. I also considered using an absolute value function, but I haven't done anything.
I think, but I haven't proven it, that the function must be bijective.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\arctan(x)$.

Comment: If $x<y$ but $y-x\ge a$ apply the "restricted monotonicity" to the pairs $(x,x+a/2), (x+a/2,x+a), (x+a,x+3a/2), \ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that for $a >\epsilon > \delta > 0$ and any real $r$ we have for $y = r + \epsilon$ and $x = r + \delta$ that $0 < y-x < a$ since $y-x = \epsilon - \delta < a$. So we have that our function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in the interval (r, r+a), and by considering the intervals $(n\frac{a}{2}, n\frac{a}{2} + a)$ where $n$ is any integer, we see our function is in fact strictly increasing everywhere. In fact, any $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is strictly increasing has our desired property.

Now that we know $f$ is strictly increasing, we see it must be injective since if $x \neq y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$ this would contradict $f$ being strictly increasing. To show it does not need to be surjective, you can consider the function arctan(x), as Jan Bohr has mentioned.